# Trying to understand how a WordPress theme has been constructed - Strange Custom Post Field

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to work out how a theme has been constructed,  from the following code I can see that a Custom Post Type of Stores is being created....

```
register_taxonomy( APP_TAX_STORE,
        array( 'promo_code','sale_offers','in_store','coupon' ),
        array(  'hierarchical' => true,
                'labels' => array(
                        'name' => __( 'Stores', 'appthemes'),
                        'singular_name' => __( 'Store', 'appthemes'),
                        'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Stores', 'appthemes'),
                        'all_items' => __( 'All Stores', 'appthemes'),
                        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Store', 'appthemes'),
                        'update_item' => __( 'Update Store', 'appthemes'),
                        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Store', 'appthemes'),
                        'add_or_remove_items' => __( 'Add or remove Stores', 'appthemes'),
                        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate Stores with commas', 'appthemes'),
                        'choose_from_most_used' => __( 'Choose from the most common Stores', 'appthemes'),
                        'new_item_name' => __( 'New Store Name', 'appthemes')
                ),
                'show_ui' => true,
                'query_var' => true,
                'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
                'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => $store_tax_base_url, 'with_front' => false, 'hierarchical' => true ),
        )
);
```

That bit I understand, but there also seems to be a field called 'clpr_store_phone' which is being created with....

```
function clpr_edit_stores($tag, $taxonomy) {
$the_store_phone = get_metadata($tag->taxonomy, $tag->term_id, 'clpr_store_phone', true);
?>

<tr class="form-field">
    <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="clpr_phone"><?php _e('Phone Number', 'appthemes'); ?></label></th>
    <td><input type="text" name="clpr_store_phone" id="clpr_store_phone" value="<?php echo $the_store_phone; ?>"/><br /></td>
</tr>

<?php
}
add_action('stores_edit_form_fields', 'clpr_edit_stores', 10, 2);

function clpr_save_stores($term_id, $tt_id) {
if (!$term_id) return;

if(isset($_POST['clpr_store_phone']))
  update_metadata($_POST['taxonomy'], $term_id, 'clpr_store_phone',     $_POST['clpr_store_phone']);
}
add_action('edited_stores', 'clpr_save_stores', 10, 2);
```

This is where I am confused,  what is being set up here?  Is 'clpr_store_phone' a custom field within a taxonomy?

Can someone shed some light on it?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at what limited code you have posted it seems they have created a custom meta table for the taxonomy types.

If you look up the [get_metadata](http://phpxref.ftwr.co.uk/wordpress/nav.html?wp-includes/meta.php.source.html#l254) function it tries to get the meta value from the cache, and if it's not there it calls [update_meta_cache](http://phpxref.ftwr.co.uk/wordpress/nav.html?wp-includes/meta.php.source.html#l514) to prime the meta cache. update_meta_cache uses a function called _get_meta_table (see below since I can only post two links) which generates a table name from the `$meta_type` value passed to `get_metadata` since the taxonomy type doesn't exist they would have to create a custom table and add the table name to `$wpdb`

```
function _get_meta_table($type) {
    global $wpdb;

    $table_name = $type . 'meta';

    if ( empty($wpdb->$table_name) )
        return false;

    return $wpdb->$table_name;
}
```

phpxref.ftwr.co.uk/wordpress/nav.html?wp-includes/meta.php.source.html#l811

Comment: Thanks for that, I think I am further along in understanding what is going on.  If there were values in the clpr_store_phone field then how would I go about retrieving them?

Comment: I take it that this line update_metadata($_POST['taxonomy'], $term_id, 'clpr_store_phone', $_POST['clpr_store_phone']); is storing the clpr_store_phone data.  How would I change this into a get_metadata command to retrieve it?